# Audio input not working Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio-recording, input, mixer

My audio input is a mix of my mic output and my sound card output. I'd like it to be just my mic output. I was able to do so in Ubuntu 9.04 but the interface is 9.10 is totally changed and I tried every my creativity was able to think.

It's really annoying when talking to other people over the internet because they keep hearing their voice back.

I'm not sure I explained it in clear way so I'll give you an example:

**What I do:**
I put an mp3 on play or a video on youtube then open a recorder and start to talk on my mic.

**What happens:**
both my voice and audio from mp3/youtube get reordered, even if I put headphones volume to 0 (via hardware).

**What I'd like to happen:**
Only my voice should be recorded.

I'm sure I'm missing some technical term, but that's the problem and I'd like to solve it in Ubuntu 9.10, any idea?

Comment: did you ever get this solved? Are you still on 9.10?

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Sound Preferences" and select the "Input" tab. See if you can view any changes if you speak into the microphone. If not, type the following into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install axle
```

You might have to restart your computer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play around with [alsamixer](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like stereomix is activated. Unfortunately I do not know where to do this in ubuntu, but you may have a look if there is a slider for stereomix in your sound options. If you find such a slider, make sure to set it to 0.